# Can't seem to pass data to component via props in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I'm making a dynamic table using Vue 3 as a learning project, in which the user can add or remove rows from the table, among other things. I'm using a `table-row` component to create the row, and a `table-data` component to create data cells within that row. Adding a row is done via the following code:

```
const app = Vue.createApp({
    data() {
        return {
            tableRows: [],
        }
    },

    methods: {
        addRow() {
            this.tableRows.push(-1);
        },
    },
})
```

What I need to do is to pass the array `TableRows` and `index` to the `table-row` component, in order to perform a row delete operation, as shown in this code:

```
app.component('table-row', {
    props: {
        tableRows: Array,
        index: Number,
    },

    methods: {
        deleteRow(index) {
            this.tableRows.splice(index, 1);
        }
    },

    template: `
        <tr>
            <table-data></table-data>
            <table-data></table-data>
            <table-data></table-data>
            <table-data></table-data>
            <button @click="deleteRow">Delete Row</button>
        </tr>
    `
})
```

The issue is that both the values of `TableRows` and `index` are undefined (as seen in the Vue DevTools), which means the props are not being passed from the parent to the child component. I think that's the reason why this error pops up whenever I click the Delete Row button:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'splice')

Here's a screenshot from Vue DevTools. You can see that the props variables have undefined values:

[image: Vue DevTools screenshot]

I'm not really sure why is this happening, or what I can do to remedy this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not 100% about this, but I thought you had to pass props using a ```v-on``` binding from the parent in order to use them in the child. You could try adding the template html to the parent instead of the child and bind the props using ```v-on``` there.

Comment: @Chaos_Is_Harmony As far as I understand components and props, that's not necessarily the case. Examples on Vue Guide page pass the props... directly, I guess? I'm not sure what their method is called. As for moving the template into the parent, I guess that's an idea. I'll try that and see what I can do with it, but it won't address the issue I'm facing right now.

Comment: @Chaos_Is_Harmony, You were right. I had to bind the variable to the component in the HTML itself. Something like ```<table-row :tableRow="tableRow" :index="index"></table-row>```. However, the ```tableRow``` still is undefined, even though the ```index``` variable is being passed onto the component. I suspect data mismatch, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Edit to the previous comment: It's not a type mismatch. Seems like ```tableRows``` is an attribute (if I were to believe Vue DevTools), and not a prop. Do I have to open a new question now ?-? ?

Comment: I posted an answer with a more detailed answer that I hope helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all props must first be declared in the parent's data before they're bound as props in children

```
"PARENT"
<template>
...
  <Child :tableRows="tableRows" />
...
</template>

...
<script>
 ...
  data() {
    return {
      tableRows: []
    }
  }
  ...
</script>
```

```
"CHILD"
...
</script>
  ...
  props: {
    tableRows: Array
  }
  ...
</script>
```

As for index, you will likely have to `emit` the event back up to the parent on click.

```
"CHILD"
<template>
...
  <button @click="$emit('deleteRow')">Delete Row</button>
...
</template>
```

Here you'd have to deal with it in the parent, where e is the value associated with the event--in this case, presumably the index you want.

```
"PARENT"
<template>
...
  <Child @deleteRow="deleteRow(e)" :tableRows="tableRows" />
...
</template>
```

Comment: Yes! This worked perfectly. I had to tweak a couple of things, but what you described was the answer I was looking for. Thank you.
Funny thing, when I passed ```i``` instead of ```index```, the function still worked as it should've, albeit not before issuing a warning in the console. Did I encounter some JavaScript hijinks because of it being untyped?

Comment: Wish I knew. I'm rather new to Vue.js and javascript, but I had encountered this problem previously. That's why I remembered: Parent->Child = Props; Child->Parent = Emit.